# Automatically use pprint to display variables in the PyCharm console

Tags: python, pycharm

I have gotten used to PyScripter, which prints variables in the debug console using pprint. Yes, I know that I can manually import and use pprint each time, but what I'm after is to use pprint as the default when interactively running Python code from the console.

Comment: Related: [Printing a long dictionary in the PyCharm console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21273666/2529619)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following line to the beginning of the console startup script:

```
from pprint import pprint
```

To get there, open 'Settings' and click on 'Build, Execution, Deployment', 'Console', 'Python Console', 'starting script'...

Then, you can use pprint in place of print. This doesn't help when entering a expression without a print statement though.